# VB.Net Winform Radiobutton has all attributes on properties set to ReadOnly = True

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, radio-button

This is my first question here so bear with me.

I've encountered a bug in my software where multiple radio buttons in a given control are both capable of being selected simultanously as shown here. Note that this is a very large program.

[Multiple Radio Buttons Selected in One Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omcXh.png)

While debugging this I found the cause of this behavior is that the ReadOnly attribute on the "Checked" property for the RadioButton class is set to true. In additional, it seems as though the ReadOnly attribute for all properties on the RadioButton are set to True. I was able to confirm this was causing the unexpected behavior by changing the value of the ReadOnly attribute via reflection back to false. Interestingly, when this occured every radio button in my application experiences the same problem.

I was able to track down at what point the attributes changes. In a different form I show some objects on a property grid, when I set the SelectedObject of that property grid to the object thats when all of the attributes change. The form with the property grid and the form with the radio button are not common in anyway.

I've been unable to track down the source of this problem for some time now. If anyone has any ideas as to how this is possible it may be able to help me figure out where the issue is in my program.

Here are pictures of my debug window showing the ReadOnly attribute value on a radiobutton just before and just after I set the SelectedObject property for the property grid

[Just Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOVQ5.png)

[Just After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTcOR.png)

Thank you.

Edit 1:

Here is the code that sets the property grid. Line 179. While debugging there are 3 different sub property objects that need to be shown in different tabs. The first causes no issues. The second does.

[Property Grid Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYDYF.png)

Edit 2:

**Solution**

Thanks to all the people who commented. I was actually able to figure out the solution to the problem with help from the following thread.

[Setting ReadOnly Property in PropertyGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992719/setting-readonly-property-in-propertygrid-sets-all-properties-readonly)

Basically, there was a spot in my code where I was setting the ReadOnly status of all attributes in an object to True. It seems as though there is some kind of common "ReadOnly" attribute that is shared among all objects if they do not have a special  define.

My original solution was to first check if the ReadOnlyAttribute existed before setting its value like so.

[Original Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JI7ze.png)

However this was returning True for properties defined like this

[Non ReadOnly Property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JI7ze.png)

But False for properties like this

[ReadOnly Property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk7Il.png)

My guess again is that there is some kind of inherit attribute that was getting found.

My solution therefore was to check with the following function.

[Final Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSc3N.png)

Putting this check in my SetReadOnly() function solved my problem.

Comment: Are these controls added at design time or run time? Could you show some code?

Comment: The controls are all added in the designer. There is some work in places that does adjust the ReadOnly property of some of my classes for display in property grids; however, from what I can tell none of it is being called. I do call some code that adjusts browsable properties; however, even if I comment that out it still happens.

Comment: Added Code to the question

Comment: Also I just realized that the Tab Control is placed by the designer with no tab pages but the tab pages and property grids are added at run time

Comment: Is there any data binding involved?  TabPages are a source of much unexpected behavior.  See: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/50119854/2592875](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50119854/2592875).

Comment: There is no data binding nothing beyond me setting an object to be shown in the property grid. The object is a simple class that has several proeprties that are shown.

Comment: I just tried completely removing the tab control from the form and having a single property grid that I set the selected object of directly but the problem still occured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution

Thanks to all the people who commented. I was actually able to figure out the solution to the problem with help from the following thread.

[Setting ReadOnly Property in PropertyGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992719/setting-readonly-property-in-propertygrid-sets-all-properties-readonly)

Basically, there was a spot in my code where I was setting the ReadOnly status of all attributes in an object to True. It seems as though there is some kind of common "ReadOnly" attribute that is shared among all objects if they do not have a special define.

My original solution was to first check if the ReadOnlyAttribute existed before setting its value like so.

[Original Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShWl5.png)

However this was returning True for properties defined like this

[Non ReadOnly Property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fz2Vk.png)

But False for properties like this

[ReadOnly Property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4mQm.png)

My guess again is that there is some kind of inherit attribute that was getting found.

My solution therefore was to check with the following function.

[Final Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDSnW.png)

Putting this check in my SetReadOnly() function solved my problem.